# Why does the declaration of a DateTime const give a compiler error but not optional parameter?

Tags: c#, datetime, compilation, constants, optional-parameters

I'm no good with titles, methinks. But bear with me: I know why reference types in themselves cannot be declared const - they must be fully evaluable at compile time. Therefore, the only possible values for constants of reference types are string and a null reference.

So it makes sense that `const DateTime x = some date` is not valid. But following that logic, I should not be able to pass for example `DateTime d1 = default(DateTime)` as an optional parameter, just like I cannot declare a `const DateTime d1 = default(DateTime)`, since optional parameters have to be compile-time constants? This has always been something I've had that attitude of "meh. just the way it is" about, but I got curious now.

Isn't a compile-time constant a compile-time constant? As in, a constant is a constant?

Of course, it might just as well be that my IDE (Visual Studio) just gives an error because DateTime is not allowed as `const` and it would've compiled fine as a `default(DateTime)` or `null` reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the msdn article on [optional parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).
When the data type is a value type (enum, struct) you may initiate an optional parameter with an empty constructor:

```
static void Foo(string s, DateTime opt = new DateTime())
```

Or with the default keyword. This isn't true for reference types.

Comment: Obviously the question was unclear - I know that. What I'm asking (and I thought that was obvious with the phrasing "Isn't a compile-time constant a compile-time constant? As in, a constant is a constant?") is _why_ for example a `default(DateTime)` is allowed as an optional parameter (which has to be a compile-time constant) but cannot be declared a compile-time constant (`const`). Both are compile-time constants and there should, in my mind, be no difference in an optional parameter (compile-time constant) and a const. But there clearly is, since one raises an error and the other does not.

Comment: An optional parameter must be a compile time constanct **only** when a reference type is involved. `default(DateTime)` is not a compile time constant so you can't initialize a const variable with it, but since `DateTime` is a value type you can initiate an optional parameter using an empty constructor or the default keyword.

Comment: Ah, it's VS that's being tricky, saying "default parameter value for 'foo' has to be a compile-time constant". That's what made it confusing and why the MSDN article didn't make it any clearer. Did not realize optional parameters could be other than compile-time constants. The more you know! Thanks!